# CSS: styling the jquery ui date picker?

Tags: css

I'm trying to style the jquery UI date picker.

Everything works fine with one exception.

I need to make everything centered but I can't seem to achieve that.

Here what i have so far:

```js
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
        inline: true,
        firstDay: 1,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
    });
```

```css
.ui-datepicker,
.ui-datepicker table,
.ui-datepicker tr,
.ui-datepicker td,
.ui-datepicker th {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


.ui-datepicker {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 35px;
    cursor: default;
 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 24px;
 
    background: #fff;
 
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border:solid 1px #e91e62;
}


.ui-datepicker-header {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}
 
.ui-datepicker-title { text-align: center; }
 
.ui-datepicker-month {
    position: relative;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: #e91e62;
}
 
.ui-datepicker-year {
    padding-left: 8px;
    color: #e91e62;
}



.ui-datepicker-month:before {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 0;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    content: '';
 
    background: #a5cd4e;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#a5cd4e), color-stop(100%,#6b8f1a));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%,#6b8f1a 100%);
 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


.ui-datepicker-prev,
.ui-datepicker-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
 
.ui-datepicker-prev {
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
 
.ui-datepicker-next {
    right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
 
.ui-datepicker-prev span,
.ui-datepicker-next span{
    display: block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
 
    background-image: url(../img/arrows.png);
}
 
.ui-datepicker-prev span { background-position: 0px 0px; }
 
.ui-datepicker-next span { background-position: -5px 0px; }
 
.ui-datepicker-prev-hover span { background-position: 0px -10px; }
 
.ui-datepicker-next-hover span { background-position: -5px -10px; }


.ui-datepicker-calendar th {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
 
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #a8a8a8;
    width:100%;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar td {
    padding: 0 7px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 26px;
}
 
.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default {
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    outline: none;
 
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
 
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}


.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active {
    color: #e91e62;
    border: 1px solid #e91e62;
}
 
.ui-datepicker-other-month .ui-state-default { color: #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="calendar">
</div>
```

If you look at the example above, you will see a gap which is not wanted and the content of the calendar is not really centered!

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Here is a fiddle as well if needed: https://jsfiddle.net/u7cocxdy/2/

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had a `width:100%` in there (`.ui-datepicker-calendar th`), which i deleted. This got rid of the gap. I then used `margin: 0 auto` to center the table.

```js
$('#calendar').datepicker({
  inline: true,
  firstDay: 1,
  showOtherMonths: true,
  dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker,
.ui-datepicker table,
.ui-datepicker tr,
.ui-datepicker td,
.ui-datepicker th {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.ui-datepicker {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 35px;
  cursor: default;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px #e91e62;
}

.ui-datepicker-header {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
}

.ui-datepicker-title {
  text-align: center;
}

.ui-datepicker-month {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 15px;
  color: #e91e62;
}

.ui-datepicker-year {
  padding-left: 8px;
  color: #e91e62;
}

.ui-datepicker-month:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  content: '';
  background: #a5cd4e;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #a5cd4e), color-stop(100%, #6b8f1a));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #a5cd4e 0%, #6b8f1a 100%);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev,
.ui-datepicker-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev {
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.ui-datepicker-next {
  right: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev span,
.ui-datepicker-next span {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-image: url(../img/arrows.png);
}

.ui-datepicker-prev span {
  background-position: 0px 0px;
}

.ui-datepicker-next span {
  background-position: -5px 0px;
}

.ui-datepicker-prev-hover span {
  background-position: 0px -10px;
}

.ui-datepicker-next-hover span {
  background-position: -5px -10px;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar th {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #a8a8a8;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar td {
  padding: 0 7px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-default {
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active {
  color: #e91e62;
  border: 1px solid #e91e62;
}

.ui-datepicker-other-month .ui-state-default {
  color: #ccc;
}

.ui-datepicker table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="calendar">
</div>
```